# Beamer: splitting environment across \newenvironment

Tags: beamer, environments

I would like to define a new environment in Beamer that creates a frame containing only an `itemize` (and maybe some other stuff once I this basic case to work). The following

```
\newenvironment{itemizeframe}
{
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
}
{
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
```

called as

```
\begin{itemizeframe}
\item test
\end{itemizeframe}
```

does not compile and outputs

> Runaway argument? \let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook
>   \@checkend {docume\ETC.

Any idea on what's happening? I am no specialist but I guess this has to do with the internal machinery of `beamer`.

Comment: See the documentation of the `environment`-key on page 61 of the beamer documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick.

```
\newenvironment{itemizeframe}
{
  \begin{frame}[fragile,environment=itemizeframe]
   \begin{itemize}
 }
 {
   \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}
```

Here a little explanation from the [user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

The environment name (itemizeframe) is used to determine the end of the scanning when gathering the frame contents. Normally, the frame ends when a line reading
\end{frame} is reached. However, if you use \begin{frame}
inside another environment, you need to use this option. The environment option is useful only in conjunction with the fragile option.